# Pros and Cons of using Choice Router in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule. I have multiple flows. My selection for multiple flow is based on choice router. I just want to know the Pros and Cons of Using Choice Router . How maximum use of choice router will effect the performance.

How choice router works internally and how it upgrade and degrade the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes:

- As a general principle, the time spent in a choice router is orders of magnitude less than what Mule spends waiting on I/O with all the systems in interacts with. So don't worry too much about performance beforehand, but load test and measure.
- Choice routers short circuit at the first route whose expression is true so performance will be affected by the number of routes you have.
- Performance is also affected by the type and complexity of expression you run.

Tips:

- Consider nesting choice routers, refining options in nested routers. Extract nested routers in private flows, and call them with `flow-ref`, for readability.
- Pre-compute decision expressions and store them in flow variables: for example don't run the same xpath expression in different routes but pre-compute it and store it, then use the flow variable in the expressions.